# Use token in php code on drupal site

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am using some tokens in my drupal site.

I have some php code where i need to use the token.

```
print '[token]';
```

This works perfect but i need to use it in a function like

```
myfunctionname('[token]') {
}
```

This doesn't work. How can u use this token in php code without using the print function. 
I am trying to encode the string wit a special function. So i must use the value from that token as parameter in the function.

Comment: I am still facing this issue, need help. I tried t() and token_replace() no luck.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding some token on the simplenews tokens.
Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I have the same problem - this is not an answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the `t()` function like `t('[token]')`.

But it seems that [token_replace()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--token.inc/function/token_replace/7) is the function you like to use.

Comment: I forgot to say that i tried the token_replace() function already. token_replace('simplenews-subscriber:mail');   also tried token_replace('[simplenews-subscriber:mail]');

Comment: @SvenVdb: As long as it is not a global token, you need to pass the required 'base' data to `token_replace()` (I added the documentation link in the answer above).